# How to alert the defined function in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to alert the defined function :

```
function calPricing{ Text }

alert(calPricing());
```

It's not working.

Comment: What's going on with the brackets here? o.O `jQuery(this).val() == 'betteroption') {`

Comment: Please check your syntax first ... open your console to check for errors

Comment: Radio buttons should have the same name but **not** the same ID. Id's should be unique

Answer (score 0):

**You can test whether a specific one is checked using jQuery as follows:**

```
if ($("#radio1").prop("checked")) {
   // do something
}

// OR
if ($("#radio1").is(":checked")) {
   // do something
}

// OR if you don't have ids set you can go by group name and value
// (basically you need a selector that lets you specify the particular input)
if ($("input[name='radioGroup'][value='1']").prop("checked"))
```

**You can get the value of the currently checked one in the group as follows:**

```
$("input[name='radioGroup']:checked").val();
```

Comment: if ($("#radio1").prop("checked")) {
   // do something
}

its not working for me